# Show three letters of authors' names in biblatex alphabetically

Tags: biblatex

I would like to install the new version of the style but I cannot remember the hack I did  in order to display more letters from the author's names.
The hack was directly into the `.bst` or `.cst` files.
In any case, my citations appear as,

> MijKomSpi09b

where there is three authors and for each one, I wish to display their first three letters. Beyond three authors, I just want the first three letters of the first authors (like `Mij+09`).

Is it possible to do that directly in the `.tex` file? Currently my setting is

```
 \usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=nyt, citestyle=ieee-alphabetic,
             bibstyle=ieee-alphabetic,  maxnames=3,minnames=1,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
```

and this displays the first three letters only when there is one authors. For multiple authors, it is of the form `AHW09b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Biber, we can use `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` to change the label format, we will also have to set `minalphanames=1` (that is with `ieee-alphabetic`, otherwise you might need `minalphanames=1, maxalphanames=3`)

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}    
  }
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=nyt, style=ieee-alphabetic, minalphanames=1, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}    
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \cite{companion,knuth:ct} and \cite{baez/article} \cite{aksin}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]